# Numpy polynomial generation

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.polynomial.Polynomial to generate a second degree polynomial on the domain 0 to 0.02 such that it fits the points (0,0) and (0.02,16)

The resulting polynomial object is as so:

[image]

So with coefficients `[4. 8. 4.]`

If I run `plt.plot(*pA.linspace(), label="Ascending", color="orange")`, the result is as expected:

[image]

However, if I plot this polynomial on another tool, for example WolframAlpha, the result is completely different:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2%2B8x%2B4+;+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C+0.02

[image]

Can anybody help? Quite confused

Edit, as requested, the polynomial object can be obtained with:

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pA = Polynomial(coef=[4.,8.,4.], domain=[0,0.02])
plt.plot(*pA.linspace(), label="Ascending", color="orange")
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you show us your actual code?

Comment: @ninesalt you can obtain an equivalent polynomial with p = Polynomial(coef=[4.,8.4.], domain=[0,0.02])

Comment: from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pA = Polynomial(coef=[4.,8.,4.], domain=[0,0.02])
plt.plot(*pA.linspace(), label="Ascending", color="orange")

Comment: The intercept should be 4, so there's something wrong with the way you're plotting/the coefficients aren't being interpreted as you intend.

Comment: @Mako212 there's no R anywhere

Comment: How can the intercept be 4  if the line is passing through 0,0

Comment: @Bazingaa because for the given polynomial, `f(0) = 4`

Comment: @Mako212: But then the equation (coefficients) are wrong because the curve is fitted to pas through the point (0,0) which means it should yield `f(0) = 0`

Comment: about 'domain' and 'window' see: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/polynomial_models.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial` object with a `coef` array of `array([4., 8., 4.])` doesn't necessarily represent the polynomial `4 + 8x + 4x^2`. Input is rescaled according to the `Polynomial` object's `domain` and `window` first, mapping `domain[0]` to `window[0]` and `domain[1]` to `window[1]`. I don't know why `domain` and `window` exist, but they do.

If you told Wolfram Alpha to plot 4+8x+4x^2 from -1 to 1 instead of from 0 to 0.02, you'd see a graph shaped more like your matplotlib output:

[image]

Comment: Oh that starts to make sense. So if I wanted to re-create the object given the domain and coefs would pA = Polynomial(coef=[4.,8.,4.], domain=[0,0.02]) work? From the docs (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) I see that the windows defaults to [-1,1]. So I shouldn't need to specify anything else.

Comment: Ok that's great thanks, I see from the docs that domain : (2,) array_like, optional

Domain to use. The interval [domain[0], domain[1]] is mapped to the interval [window[0], window[1]] by shifting and scaling. The default value is [-1, 1]. I assume I shouldn't concern myself too much with that then?

Comment: All 3 coefficients positive and the curve passing through (0, 0) is mathematically impossible. The coefficients seems to be wrong. There **should** be no constant term here

Comment: @Bazingaa true, but there is... You can run the snippet I posted in my question and you'll see the output of a numpy Polynomial with such domain and coefs passes through (0,0).

Comment: But then you should re-check your code. You are making the fit curve to pass through (0, 0), but your resulting fit is passing through (0, 4). Don't you smell some error in the fitting?

Comment: @Bazingaa: You're overlooking the domain/window handling.

Comment: I am just going by OP's wordings in his/her question **such that it fits the points (0,0) and (0.02,16)** but yeah, well.

Comment: Found this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html - As can be seen, the “good” parts have shrunk to insignificance. In using Chebyshev polynomials for fitting we want to use the region where x is between -1 and 1 and that is what the window specifies. However, it is unlikely that the data to be fit has all its data points in that interval, so we use domain to specify the interval where the data points lie. When the fit is done, the domain is first mapped to the window by a linear transformation and the usual least squares fit is d...

Comment: @Bazingaa it does, I just wasn't aware there were extra transformations involved

Comment: Ok, the comment above sums it all

Answer (score 7):

You can convert to the unscaled and unshifted form of the coefficients.

```
In [1]: from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

In [2]: p = P([4.,8.,4.], domain=[0,0.02])

In [3]: p.convert()
Out[3]: Polynomial([     0.,      0.,  40000.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Having to go back to this nearly two years later, this answer is really useful.

Comment: Dang but this is useful

Answer (score 4):

An example:

```
p = P( [0, 0, 1], domain=[0, 1], window=[-1, 1] )
```

does `p(x)` in two steps:

```
1: domaintowindow: x -> w = 2x - 1  # 0 to -1, 1 to 1
2: [0 0 1] is squaring, w -> w^2

p( x ): x -> w = 2x - 1
          -> w^2  # [0 0 1]
          = (2x - 1)^2  = 4x^2 - 4x + 1  # p.convert()
```

So if you want a polynomial `p()` in another system, you need both steps --
don't forget `domaintowindow()`.

(Make a rough sketch:
`w^2` on window [-1 1] is a parabola, 0 in the middle, 1 at the ends;
`p(x)` on domain [0 1] is a parabola, 0 in the middle, 1 at the ends.)